# GZIP multiple files into 1 file gz

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to backup all my files that older than 30 days into 1 archive file.

I try using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find all files that older than 30 days and store it into backup.tar.gz
find ~/Algorithm/test/PDF -mtime +30 -exec tar czvf backup.tar.gz {} \;
```

But unfortunately it backup just the last file not all the files, what I found that the script above just replace the backup.tar.gz first with the last one.

If there is something missing with my script please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a `\;` to terminate find -exec, it runs the command once for every file. So you ran tar many times, each time creating a tar file that contained a single file, and each one overwrote the previous one.

Change the `\;` to a `+` and find will group multiple files into a single run of the exec command, so it will work a little better, but there will be a problem lurking. When there are too many files to fit into a command line, find will split it up and you'll have a repeat of the previous problem.

To really do this cleanly, you want `find` to generate a list of files that `tar` can read, instead of trying to fit them all on the command line. And to handle all filenames correctly, you'll want to have the list in '\0'-separated format. GNU tar&find can do that:

```
find ~/Algorithm/test/PDF -mtime +30 -print0 |
  tar --null --files-from=- -czvf backup.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` executes the function for each file it finds. You need to pass the list to the function for this to work. Executing the find as a sub function and passing it to the `tar` `gzip` chain should work.

```
 tar czvf - $(find ~/Algorithm/test/PDF -mtime +30) | gzip -c backup.tar.gz
```

Comment: This will not work if any of the file names contain spaces, or if there is a large number of found files (too many resulting arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already have an existing, ungzipped `backup.tar` you can also append files to the tarball

```
 find . -exec tar rf backup.tar && gzip backup.tar
```

I do not now how this benchmarks against the other methods, but it should work as intended.